# 'in' operator in Python not behaving as expected on the same string

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am using Python2.7 and I am facing a rather peculiar problem in a program where I receive data over a socket and I check for two strings in the data received. The program is behaving awkwardly, one check returns true while other false, which I am not able to understand, why. Please help if I am doing something wrong here. Find the code below:

```
import socket
import sys
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('172.16.16.121', 10000)
print >> sys.stderr, 'starting as server on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print "Status 2: " + str("#" in data)
                if "#" in data:
                    input_str = "".join(data)
                    print input_str
                    print "Status: " + str("Restart" in str(input_str))
                    if "RestartService".lower() in str(input_str).lower():
                        print "Kill them all"
    except Exception,e:
        sock.close()
        connection.close()
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        sock.close()
        connection.close()
```

Output registered on console is:

starting as server on 172.16.16.121 port 10000

waiting for a connection

Status 2: True

RestartService#

Status: False

When I use `repr(input_str)` I get:

```
'\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00S\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00#'
```

Comment: It is more likely to *not be the same string*. Use `print repr(input_str)` to verify what actual data is there.

Comment: What is the content of `input_str` at the time you want your `if` to match it?

Comment: `data` is already a string, why did you use `"".join(data)`? That's a waste of time; it takes the individual characters of the `data` string, and joins them together again to *form the exact same string*. You don't need to keep calling `str()` on a string either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I got the following output: '\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00S\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00#' returned after repr(input_str) . What I understood from ASCII sheet is, it is a null byte ASCII control character. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: that's UTF-16 data. Decode it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving **UTF-16 encoded** data. Decode this to Unicode strings first; with the `\x00` bytes coming first this is using UTF-16 in big-endian order:

```
input_str = data.decode('utf-16-be')
if u"restartservice" in input_str.lower():
```

Note that I used a Unicode string literal (`u'...'`) to test against the decoded text; that way you avoid implicit decoding and encoding, which can lead to further exceptions if one of the two operands doesn't cleanly decode or encode as ASCII.

Demo:

```
>>> input_str = '\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00S\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00#'
>>> input_str.decode('utf-16-be')
u'RestartService#'
>>> 'restartservice' in input_str.decode('utf-16-be').lower()
True
```

You may want to read up on what Unicode is, and how to best handle this in Python code; I strongly recommend the following articles:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)